# How do I have my internal microphone and headphones be used simultaneously under PulseAudio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, headphones

I just wiped my hard drive and installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu! I got it all warm and cozy, but then I found out about how my microphone did not work in Ubuntu when I have my headphones plugged in, and my dreams were crushed... Anyway, here is my problem, my headset microphone is broken and has been for a while, but I need my microphone for skype. I cannot use my speakers with skype because I live in a house with other humans, and I am not so great with the whole "hearing thing". I need to use my internal microphone along with my headphones, but PulseAudio wont have it... I do I get PulseAudio to allow me to use my Internal microphone with my headphones?    **TLDR:** internal microphone and headset wont work together because PulseAudio requires that the headset works exclusively with the broken microphone on the headset. How do I get PulseAudio to accept and strengthen the friendship between my internal laptop microphone and my headset?

Answer (score 5):

Install **PulseAudio Volume Control** from Ubuntu Software Center, which has a lot of options to choose from.

After installing, in application's "Output Devices" tab choose your headphones and in "Input Devices" tab choose internal microphone. By pressing green button you can choose which device will always remain as default (device which is not selected will be default, not the opposite)

You can also choose settings per specific application, start Skype call and go to "Recording" tab where you can select internal microphone and in "Playback" you can select headphones.

Additional option is to choose suitable profile in "Configuration" tab.

Comment: As an addition: I had to unplug and plug in the headphones in order to have it recognized as headphone whit out a microphone.